# Armature parent with automatic weights swaps the legs

Tags: armature, weight-painting

I'm fairly new to weight painting and armatures, so I heavily rely on automated tools. So far parenting an armature with automatic weights was working perfectly. However this time it's not working.
See screenshot: Right leg is selected, the weight is on the left leg. Same for the lower part. Back bones are not even weighted.

[image]

I'm not sure if this is another setting I overlook or just a bug, but any help is appreciated

Comment: Make sure you've applied the object scale. Have you tried to correct with a brush? Make sure that in the N panel > Tool > Brush > Options you've disabled Front Face Only and enable 2D Falloff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the scale and rotation to the model before, so I guess the exact solution was to recalculate the normals. I'm not sure exactly, however applying loc,rot, scale and recalculating normals together fixed the issue.